# Why does byte representation in Java store data in decimal?

Tags: java, jvm

I was debugging a problem where I created a byte array from binary representation of strings such as below.

1. While debugging the array just to see how it is stored, I could see them stored internally as decimals. Why is that?
2. When it gets interpreted as bytecode I am assuming it will get converted as binary. Then why not store in binary in the first place.

```
 String[] binArray = {"10101","11100","11010","00101"};
    byte[]bytes = new byte[binArray.length];
    for (int i=0; i< binArray.length;i++){
        bytes[i] = Byte.parseByte(binArray[i],2);
}
```

I may be missing something here. Hence request your guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a very general misunderstanding.

In some sense, **all** data is stored "in binary form". Particularly, the integral numerical values, like `byte`, `short`, `int` etc., are internally all stored in binary form. This internal representation is known as the [Two's complement form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

<sup>(For floating point numbers, the representation is a bit more complicated: It's the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) representation - still, they are *stored* in binary form)</sup>

The key issue that has likely lead to your question is: When you just print a number, or convert them to a string, with

```
System.out.println(someByte);
```

or

```
String s = String.valueOf(someByte);
```

then by default, the decimal form is printed. Mainly because this is the most "natural" and most readable form for humans.

You can pass your bytes to [`Integer.html#toBinaryString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString-int-) to create the string representation of their binary representation:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(someByte));
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the JVM, just like any program doesn't store numeric values as "decimal" or "hexadecimal". It's just a bit-pattern in memory. Your debugger **displays** the value in decimal **format**. This is just for convenience, since most people prefer decimal to binary format for readability. For the computer itself it's just a bit-string of 8 bits length, stored as binary-value.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. While debugging the array just to see how it is stored, I could see them stored internally as decimals. Why is that?

You are seeing the byte value *displayed* in decimal. The debugger is not displaying the internal value.

> 2. When it gets interpreted as bytecode I am assuming it will get converted as binary. Then why not store in binary in the first place.

It *is* stored in binary.